# Unable to add app.config file in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, app-config, class-library

Working in Visual Studio 2017; I have added a class library in my project. Now I want to add an `app.config` file.

When I try to add by "Add new Item" but config file is missing from item list.

How can I do it?

Comment: Are you on Mac/Windows?

Comment: In my Mac, I can find it under Misc > Application Configuration File

Comment: I am using wondows.. http://prntscr.com/jebiqd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just **right click your class library**. Click on **Add -> New Item** and you should find Application Configuration file 
[image: ClassLibraryProject]
[image: ApplicationConfigFile]

**Note:** 
If you have a solution without any project or all project are unloaded, you would not find the Application Configuration File

If you are missing visual studio templates,then Close all instance of Visual Studio and Open visual studio command prompt and type,

```
devenv /installvstemplates
```

Press Enter. Let the process be complete and now open visual studio. You will get all missing templates under Visual Studio installed templates.

Comment: What is your project type? And you are searching in online in the screenshot attached, its present in Visual c# items. My screenshot also is from VS2017 professional. Did you try to reinstall vs templates

Comment: I have a webForm type of project, Now I want to add a new project of type "Class Library".. And would like to add "App.config" in class library.... But can't find it when 'Add new item".

Comment: I tried creating webForm Type project and then added new project of "Class Library" I can find "App.config" in 'Add new Item'. Try reinstalling VS2017

Comment: Thanks @akshay-bheda, I reinstalled and now I can see App.config file.

Answer (score 14):

You probably forgot to install workload .NET desktop development.

Go to installation, click to modify and include the workload .NET desktop development.

[Check image of installation screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZZfK.png)

Comment: Thanks Rafael.. that was exactly my issue.. I had initially set things up for web development and .net code, but recently went to build a class lib and couldn't find the app.config template (i did add one manually, but after adding desktop can now add a file via the new templates!!!) thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't add `app.config` using the GUI tools for my web project. However, I have added the `app.config` file manually and the build process picked it up and used it.